# WPF display record weekly wise in Datagrid with Summary

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid

[image]

I have a timesheet data, whose data model is defined as

```
public class Timesheet
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Effort { get; set; }
    public DateTime Day { get; set; }
}
```

My challenge is to display the records in the week's format. However, I'm not sure what is the best approach to design the Datagrid in a way that when the list gets bind with it, the total summary of each column also gets displayed.

Comment: try grouping as follows :             List<Timesheet> times = new List<Timesheet>();
           var weeks = times.GroupBy(x => new { week = x.Day.Date.AddDays(-1 * (int)x.Day.DayOfWeek), name = x.Name }).ToList();

Comment: That's an interesting code, I really appreciate it. Thank you

Comment: You may want to group by the sunday of the week first.  Then group by the Task Name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See following code to step through the results

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
    }
    public class Timesheet
    {
        private static List<Timesheet> timeSheets { get; set; }
        private static List<KeyValuePair<DateTime, List<Timesheet>>> weeks { get; set; }

        private int index { get; set; }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Effort { get; set; }
        public DateTime Day { get; set; }

        public void AddTimeSheets(List<Timesheet> timesheets)
        {
            Timesheet.timeSheets = timesheets;
            weeks = timesheets
                .OrderBy(x => x.Day)
                .GroupBy(x => x.Day.Date.AddDays(-1 * (int)x.Day.DayOfWeek)).Select(x => new KeyValuePair<DateTime, List<Timesheet>>(x.Key, new List<Timesheet>(x.ToList()))).ToList();

            index = 0;
        }

        public KeyValuePair<object, List<KeyValuePair<string, int[]>>> Current()
        {
            if (weeks.Count() == 0)
            {
                return new KeyValuePair<object, List<KeyValuePair<string, int[]>>>();
            }
            else
            {
                return new KeyValuePair<object, List<KeyValuePair<string, int[]>>>(weeks[index].Key, GetWeek(weeks[index].Value));
            }
        }
        public KeyValuePair<object, List<KeyValuePair<string, int[]>>> Next()
        {
            if (index >= weeks.Count() - 1)
            {
                return new KeyValuePair<object, List<KeyValuePair<string, int[]>>>();
            }
            else
            {
                index++;
                return new KeyValuePair<object, List<KeyValuePair<string, int[]>>>(weeks[index].Key, GetWeek(weeks[index].Value));
            }
        }
        public KeyValuePair<object, List<KeyValuePair<string, int[]>>> Previous()
        {
            if (index <= 0)
            {
                return new KeyValuePair<object, List<KeyValuePair<string, int[]>>>();
            }
            else
            {
                index--;
                return new KeyValuePair<object, List<KeyValuePair<string, int[]>>>(weeks[index].Key, GetWeek(weeks[index].Value));
            }
        }
        public List<KeyValuePair<string, int[]>> GetWeek(List<Timesheet> week)
        {
            List<KeyValuePair<string, int[]>> results = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int[]>>();

            var summary = week
                .GroupBy(x => x.Name)
                .ToList();

            foreach (var name in summary)
            {
                int[] effort = new int[7];
                foreach (var day in name)
                {
                    effort[(int)day.Day.DayOfWeek] += day.Effort;
                }
                results.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int[]>(name.Key, effort));
            }
            return results;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I made a few minor changes. There was an extra index++ that I removed. Also made two variables timesheets and weeks static to reduce memory.  I also was worried initially that they may be two Timesheet for the same day so I did an extra set of grouping.  I saw it was not  necessary if I made the addition of effort a '+='.